# Numpy Unique slow on a large array... is there any way to speed it up?

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, unique, slice

I am using the following code to load a numpy array, find unique dates in the first column, and then extract a slice from the numpy array based on the date. It is very slow. Is there any way to speed it up? Perhaps if I sort the big array on the first column?

```py
db = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/Share/Daily Data/Database/db_unranked.npy', 
             mmap_mode='r', allow_pickle=True)
dates = np.unique(db[:, 0])
data = db[db[:, 0] == dates[0]]
```

The db_unranked.npy arary is 21GB, approx 8 million rows and 345 columns. The np.unique is taking over 10 minutes and I have waited 30 minutes for the slice but it still hasn't finished. I'm using Google Colab.

Comment: How much memory does your system have available?

Comment: Anyway, have you considered changing your approach. For example, use an actual database with appropriate indexing?

Comment: 35GB of RAM. No... I've used np.load with mmap_mode = r. Is that not a proper database? What library do you suggest? I have tried dask but couldn't get it to work...

Comment: OK, if you have 35 GB of RAM, then you are probably running out of RAM when you do `data = db[db[:,0]==dates[0]]` which is why it's so slow. In any case, no, this isn't a proper database at all... it's a giant array. I meant something like postgres, myseql etc, but dask may be appropriate.

Comment: I have tried dask but couldn't get it to work, the documentation isn't detailed enough for me. Are there any easy to use database libraries that you would recommend? I need to make numpy arrays or cupy arrays with the slices.

Comment: I could but eventually I will not be able to so I like to learn how to database properly

Comment: no its dtype=float64

Comment: When you filter by dates[0] is that just an example or does your process require the earliest date in the array? If the latter you can speed things up by utilizing min() like this and eliminate the unique() call entirely: data = db[db[:,0]==db[:,0].min()]

Comment: I need to iterate between every date, thats why I have the np.unique line. After this comes a for loop that creates a slice for each date, saves some output and goes to the next date.

Comment: @lara_toff Do you have control over writing the original db_unranked.npy file? If so you could write one file for each date instead of to a single 21GB .npy file. Then you could just iterate over all npy files in the folder.

Comment: of course, and thats the goal, but trying to slice the 21GB file by date is very slow.

Comment: If the arrays is C-contigous (it is by default), you have a unaligned storage access. Is it on a HDD or SSD? There are better formats for arbitrary access patterns like HDF5 (if used in the right way)